# MySQL Date Search MM/DD/YYYY to MM/DD/YYYY

Tags: php, mysql, date

I have a table in MySQL That looks like the following:

```
date        |storenum   |views 
-------------------------------
08/21/2009  |42         |3  
-------------------------------
08/22/2009  |43         |1    
-------------------------------
08/21/2009  |43         |4  
-------------------------------
08/22/2009  |42         |22
-------------------------------
```

I know that this is an unconventional date format, but I am using it as opposed to YYYY-MM-DD for ease of use. Yet i have to search this database to get all "View Records" Between two dates. In general it works but when I search from a date such as 01/01/2009 to 01/01/2010 I get no results.

Does anyone have any suggestions? Constructive criticism is welcome. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In all honesty, change the way you store dates. But for working with what you have now, you could look into using [STR_TO_DATE()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) to convert these to dates that MySQL can work with.

Comment: Jon, should i change it to YYYY-MM-DD, and format them before being sent to the user?

Comment: There are various ways depending on how you are using it. Some people like using UNIX timestamps which measure the date in seconds from 1970 (Epoch time). Others like to store it in a more human-readable format, like YYYY-MM-DD.

Comment: yyyymmdd or unix time stamp, and yes, format it in the presentation layer (or in the query itself if it is logical to do so).

Comment: Itay, do not modify my answer. Please provide your own.

Comment: Thank you. Also, hello from Marietta, GA! haha.

Comment: Hello from Hiram/Dallas, GA :)

Comment: @Jonathan Sampson I was in your opinion until I read the motivation behind SO, Which is not to write an answer per user, but to refine the best answer and refine the question until you get to the optimal result. You may disagree, your right, but this is the reason I can edit Your questions and vice versa (It was not meant to enable me to fix spelling).
http://www.joelonsoftware.com/items/2008/09/15.html

Comment: @Italy Moav: Wrong - enter your own answer.  If you spend any time here, you'll see that there are multiple answers for a question.  Edit was indeed meant to fix spelling and grammar.  If your view was correct, there would only be one answer per question.  Don't be changing my answers in the future.  I don't want you misrepresenting me.  If my answer is "wrong", let me figure that out from the down votes.

Answer (score 2):

You mention ease of use - I think the case you are trying to resolve now is an example of "not so easy to use" :).

I would stick to the default format of dates in MySQL

```
yyyy-mm-dd h:i:s //php's date formatting
```

and use **DATE** fields. This will solve the searching/inserting of dates problem. Though you need to change some code to fix displaying the dates.

Answer (score 1):

what is your `date` field type? for a correct use it should be `date` or `datetime`, and seeing what you have it looks like you store you `dates` in a varchar. am I right?

This also have the advantage you can add indexes, and then search in ranges trough mysql

my suggestion is get whatever the user enter. and then convert it to a mysql date format for searching

something like:

```
<?php

$mysql_time = date('Y-m-d H:m:s' strotime('05/11/2008'));

$query = sprintf("SELECT * FROM sometable < '%s'", $mysql_time);

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the search with format "yyyyMMdd" MySql will recognize it for sure.

Comment: Even with the way i have the values stored currently?