# Greater than Date (Not datetime)

Tags: mysql, date, select

I seem to be having an issue with a greater than section of my select statement. The query is:

```
SELECT * FROM insurancedetail WHERE (insid = '31' OR insid = '29') AND enddate > '07/01/2015'
```

The enddate is not a datetime field and is just a date, but the greater than is returning results from 2011-2014 as well. I'm not sure why. Any explanation would be appreciated.

I know STR_TO_DATE(enddate,"%d/%m/%Y") would convert it for me, but would I still be able to be able to use the restriction > "certain time range" select that I initially wanted?

Comment: mysql can't recognize `07/01/2015` as real date.

Comment: You need to format your date string like `2015-07-01`. As @AbhikChakraborty says, MySQL can't tell that `07/01/2015` is a date, so it's just comparing strings.

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL Date Search MM/DD/YYYY to MM/DD/YYYY](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1319697/mysql-date-search-mm-dd-yyyy-to-mm-dd-yyyy)

Answer (score 0):

Apparently I can

SELECT enddate FROM insurancedetail WHERE insid = '31' AND STR_TO_DATE(enddate, "%d/%m/%Y") >= '2015-01-01'